# how to use PDFDataRangeTransport with 'react-pdf'?

Tags: reactjs, pdf.js, react-pdf

I have implemented pdf viewer using 'react-pdf'

the simplified code is

```
     <Document
              file={srcUrl}
              onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
            >
              {Array.from({ length: totalNumPages }, (_, index) => (
                <Page
                  key={`${index + 1}`}
                  pageNumber={index + 1}
                  scale={pageScale}
                  className="my-2"
                />
              ))}
            </Document>
```

With the code above, I guess it reads whole pdf file first then render (I am not really familiar with pdfjs and react-pdf so please correct me if I am wrong)

What I want to is to read part of the pdf file (when file is big) then render, and I believe that's what PDFDataRangeTransport does in pdfjs.

'react-pdf' document says that I can use `range` inside `file` props to use PDFDataRangeTransport but I have no idea what to put for range property.
(there's no examples and not much information on the web either..)

```
<Document
              file={{url: srcUrl, range: __what to put here??__}}
```

Does anyone know how to use it? and how to check it actually works properly?